# Colouring $n$ balls with $k$ colours

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

How many ways to colour $n$ balls with $k$ colours? Repeating and omitting colours is fine, and order is not important.

$$\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n-1}{i-1} \binom{k}{i} $$

This is what I came up with. It feels like it is a far more complicated than it needs to be. Here's my proof:

---

The $i$-composition of $n$ is equal to $\displaystyle \binom{n-1}{i-1}$.

A $3$-composition of $n$ would be $a + b + c = n$, where each term on the LHS is equal to the number of balls with a given colour. Assuming $a \ne b \ne c$, there's other compositions as well, like $b + a + c$ and $c + a + b$. They will constitute different possibilities for the colouring of the balls, as the possibilities are differing in the respective quantities of balls with a certain colour.

Given that one can omit colours, one must first start with the $1$-composition of $n$, before increasing the number of colours included, up to the total number of $k$ colours.

When in the $i$th iteration, one is colouring with $i$ out of $k$ colours, creating $\binom{k}{i}$ possibilities, as one is choosing $i$ colours from a total of $k$ colours.

---

Is the proof and solution correct? If so, are there simpler solutions and proofs for this? I could construct a pretty similar proof using $k$-bounded weak compositions, but not sure it would differ much in simplicity.

Comment: If I have understood the question, this is a routine application of [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#:~:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20combinatorial,his%20classic%20book%20on%20probability.). You have $k-$tuples which tell you how many balls are colored by each of the $k$ colors, and each  valid $k-$tuple must sum to $n$.

Comment: Can someone tell me why it is not $k^n$? Each ball has k colours to choose from…

Comment: @insipidintegrator Because order is not important. Coloring ball 1 red and ball 2 blue is the same as coloring ball 1 blue and ball 2 red in this question.

Comment: Ok thanks @DavidLukeThiessen

Comment: Looks like you are interested in [restricted partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) of $n$ into at most $k$ parts.

Comment: I am, and it is related to this problem, but here we're dealing with bounded compositions, not bounded partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work is completely correct. Here is an alternate solution.

Since order does not matter, a color assignment is uniquely specified by how many balls there with each color. Letting $x_1,\dots,x_k$ be the number of balls with each color, this means counting colorings is equivalent to counting nonnegative integer solutions to
$$
x_1+\dots+x_k=n,
$$
which is easily doable using stars and bars.

Alternatively, if you write the summation you found as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n-1}{i-1}\binom k{k-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom{n-1}{i}\binom{k}{k-1-i},
$$
then you can simplify that summation using Vandemonde's identity to a single binomial coefficient.